# displayvideo API upload creative YouTube video dv360

Tags: youtube, dv360

I'm trying to use displayvideo API to upload creatives into displayvideo.google.com
We're success to upload third party, image, but for YouTube link video, which API can do it?
Or any clues, document to do it, please help me.